# TextInputLayout label color does not change

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I am trying to change the textInputLayout label/hint color. I saw that it follows the colorPrimary  so I applied a style in which I set the primary color but it is not working.

My xml-

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:hint="hint"
    style="@style/Text"
    >
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/edittext"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

My style-

```
<style name="Text" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/white</item>
```

My layout
[image]

Comment: set this color in your primary **app theme** : `<item name="colorControlActivated">color you want to set</item>`

Comment: still the same @JeelVankhede

Comment: add  `textColorHint` attribute to `TextinputLayout`: `android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"`

Comment: does not work if you are free could you check it out??

Answer (score 1):

The new material libraries are a bit confusing. As of now in `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02` the `textColorHint` is not working but `hintTextApperance` is working, which has to be a style where the text properties can be defined.